# Oracle Apex - Link text is lost when saving

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a page with a Text area item.
Users will often use this item to store links as text. E.g.:

```
Some user text <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">user link</a>
```

But when it's saved, everything after the https gets lost, like this:

Some user text <a href="https

Instead of storing the original.
Question is, how can I store links for this case where the field will always be surrounded by text?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created such an example:

```
create table test
  (id      number primary key,
   text    varchar2(200));
```

Using the Wizard (interactive report with included form page) on apex.oracle.com (which currently runs Apex 23.1.3) with default settings, everything seems to be fine - nothing is being lost.

This is a screenshot which shows the IR page in the background and Form page on top of it. As you can see, the whole link is here:

[image]

---

Therefore:

- how do you know that text is partially saved? Did you verify in in Apex only, or did you actually `SELECT` from that table to check the contents?
- what is text column's **size**? Is it large enough to hold everything you put into the text area item?

Consider creating sample page on apex.oracle.com, share developer's credentials so that we could connect and see what you actually did.

Comment: Agreed, this could very well be a case of incorrectly (not) escaping special characters http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2017/01/escape-special-characters-apex-demo.html